# Two routers, DMZ on and firewall off, bad idea?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, firewall

First I'll explain how I set things up:

I have two routers. 
One of them is an ONT/Router (Huaweii) combo provided by my ISP with a limited user and the other one is an Asus Router ACRH1300. 
Since the ONT/Router user is limited, I couldn't change the ONT to bridge mode;
so people in other forums recommended this:

1. ONT LAN IP is 192.168.100.1 and DHCP range is 192.168.100.3 to .255
2. ONT WLAN is turned off
3. ONT connects to Asus Router from LAN1 to WAN
4. All devices are connected to Asus Router through Wi-Fi
5. Asus Router Static IP is 192.168.100.2, subnet is 255.255.255.0 and gateway is 192.168.100.1
6. Asus Router LAN IP is 192.168.50.1
7. Asus Router DHCP is off
8. Turns off Asus Router and connects ONT from LAN1 to LAN1 in Asus router
9. Turns on Asus Router

After doing this, I couldn't access Asus router settings anymore. 
Then I remembered about LAN IP, so I changed my PC IP in Windows from Automatic to Static and set it to 192.168.50.2. 
Of course, while doing that, I had no Internet, but I could access Asus settings again, then I thought about changing the mode to AP mode but that will turn off the firewall so I didn't do it (I'll explain why in a second), changed my PC IP from Static to Automatic again and here I am asking this.

The thing is that I was told by other users from same ISP and ONT that since they only give us limited access, there's a lot of problems with ports and stuff, so they recommended me to set my Asus Router as a DMZ Host (192.168.100.2), basically opening all the ports to my Asus Router and let Asus manage the ports with its firewall, does that mean that if I set the Asus Router to AP mode that will turn off both firewalls and basically I'll have no hardware firewall protection at all?

Should I remove the DMZ host? Should I NOT set my Asus Router to AP mode then?

Basically I don't know what's the best configuration anymore. 
I've read lots of stuff, I was doing this so I wouldn't have much problems with the limited ONT from my ISP but I also don't want to be totally exposed to hacking attempts or whatever, I also don't want to be under too many NAT layers.

P.S.: I'm kinda new to this networking stuff so please be patient with me.

---

Ok, so basically I have to revert to almost factory settings, except for the Static IP, this is what I understand and know how to do:

1. Give ASUS router a static IP, done.
2. Set up a DMZ on the ONT to 192.168.100.2, I did this and then I deleted it but I know how to do it.
3. Set a LAN IP to 10.0.0.1, I assume it doesn't matter as long as it is in private range? For example, the previous LAN IP in Asus router was/is 192.168.50.1, unless it's absolutely necessary to set it as 10.0.0.1, anyways I know I can set the LAN IP to anything I want, as well as netmask, DHCP and range.
4. This is what's new for me and I'm not sure if ONT has that option, I've seen a Route tab in Asus settings, but the ONT settings are more limited, does this mean that Asus router will connect to ONT through 192.168.100.1 and ONT will connect to Asus router through 10.0.0.1?
   -. I found this option in the ONT settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JcbI.jpg, is this where I'm suppose to set a route? Something like Internal Host: 10.0.0.0, External Source IP Address: 10.0.0.1 -- 255.255.255.0 (I don't know if this is the right tool, probably not).
5. If I can do step 4, disable NAT on ASUS, I know there is an option to disable NAT on the same tab where I set the Static IP, so I know this can be done.

My biggest obstacle is probably step 4 since I don't know where to find that specific setting or if it's even there.

Thanks though and I hope you can still help me.

Comment: Has you tried calling the ISP to out the modem in bridge mode? Here in the states, most of our major providers allow bridge mode, even if it means having to have the ISP do it on the backend.

Comment: Thanks for asking this because that's another question I have, I actually called them after posting this but decided to post their answer in reddit to avoid opening multiple threads for the same issue. 

The thing with my ISP is that they don't give us a "real" Public IP, it's a NAT within a NAT within a NAT, etc., when I open cmd and type tracert 8.8.8.8, it pings my ONT/Router Private IP, then it pings another private IP, then another private IP, then one last private IP and then finally pings my ISP Public IP.

I knew that before hiring, didn't mind, when I called they told me...

Comment: ...that I needed to rent a real Public IP (sometimes they tell you it has to be a Static Public IP which is more expensive than a Dynamic Public IP), but is this actually true or they are lying to me because they just want me to pay extra for something I don't really need?

Comment: It may be the limitation of their system, but “bridge” mode doesn’t care about the IP addresses on either interface. Bridge mode is a layer 2 technology. The layer before IP addresses come in to play. They can just as easily assign a private, dynamic IP to your router as they can to their ONT. however, based on what you are saying this whole exercise is pointless anyways. You won’t be able to port forward so there is no sense in playing with DMZs and bridge mode and such. Just disable the WiFi services on the ONT and plug you router’s WAN port into it. Just do steps 1-4 and done.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends a bit in what you want to do. For maximum control and flexibility I would convert the ASUS back into a router (including DHCP) server, and have it sitting between your LAN and the ONT.

To do this, give the ASUS router a static IP address.on the WAN - 192.168.100.2 is a good option.

Set up a DMZ on the ONT to 192.168.100.2 - so all traffic originating in the Internet gets redirected to it. This should be safe because its the WAN - ie untrusted - Interface.

Set a LAN IP on the router to 10.0.0.1, (netmask 255.255.255.0),  and enabLe DHCP server and range.

If possible, set a route on the ONT for 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  gateway 10.0.0.1. If you can do this then tty disabling NAT on the ASUS - these 2 steps will avoid double NAT which is nice but things will work even if you cant.

Once this is done you are effectively treating the ONT as the ISPs equipment and your router as the network you trust and manage. This is likely more secure and flexible then running the ASUS as an AP - which effectively means the ONT controls your network.